# Remove time from cells only if the time is 0:00

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have thousands of cells with date and time as follows:

```
10/22 0:00
10/22 0:00
10/22 6:00
10/22 7:00
10/22 7:00
10/22 12:30
10/23 0:00
10/25 0:00
10/25 0:00
```

However, I want to make it so if the time is 0:00, it's replaced by just date only, like this:

```
10/22
10/22
10/22 6:00
10/22 7:00
10/22 7:00
10/22 12:30
10/23
10/25
10/25
```

Is this possible? Thank you! Looked through all the date and time formats and conditionals and I haven't found anything.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#meta_instructions

Comment: The problem is that the date-time number value really looks like 12345.6789, where the 0.6789 part are the hours/minutes/seconds of the day.  So you'll still want to format the 12345 part, but leave the "time" portion blank if its zero. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a custom format that can do that, other than writing a script to go in and change the display.

Answer (score 1):

Just decided to filter by condition and add "Text ends with 0:00" and replaced all of them with m/dd.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/B1:B)))
```

[image]